# ¿Cómo poner una casilla de type text en una agrupación de type radio?

Tags: html, formularios, text, radiogroup

¿Cómo puede hacer un formulario como el siguiente?
que tenga dos opciones, pero si le doy a la tercera opción que dice otro que seleccione esa opción pero que me deje escribir, como el siguiente formulario.
Es un formulario con type=radio, que me de opciones pero en una de ellas me deje escribir en una tercera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
            <div class="cont_preguntas">
                <div id="mauticform_formulariolandingciudadcolorines_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi" data-validate="cual_es_el_primer_sentimi" data-validation-type="radiogrp" class="mauticform-row mauticform-radiogrp mauticform-field-4 mauticform-required">
                    <label class="tex_pregunta" for="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Nostalgia1">¿Cuál es el primer sentimiento que te abraza?</label>
                    <div class="mauticform-radiogrp-row">
                        <label id="mauticform_radiogrp_label_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Nostalgia0" for="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Nostalgia0" class="mauticform-radiogrp-label">
                            <input name="mauticform[cual_es_el_primer_sentimi]" class="mauticform-radiogrp-radio" id="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Nostalgia0" type="radio" value="Nostalgia">
                            <div class="cont_radio">
                                Nostalgia
                            </div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mauticform-radiogrp-row">
                        <label id="mauticform_radiogrp_label_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Alegria1" for="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Alegria1" class="mauticform-radiogrp-label">
                            <input name="mauticform[cual_es_el_primer_sentimi]" class="mauticform-radiogrp-radio" id="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Alegria1" type="radio" value="Alegría">
                            <div class="cont_radio">
                                Alegría
                            </div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mauticform-radiogrp-row">
                        <label id="mauticform_radiogrp_label_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Entusiasmo2" for="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Entusiasmo2" class="mauticform-radiogrp-label">
                            <input name="mauticform[cual_es_el_primer_sentimi]" class="mauticform-radiogrp-radio" id="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Entusiasmo2" type="radio" value="Entusiasmo">
                            <div class="cont_radio">
                                Entusiasmo
                            </div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mauticform-radiogrp-row">
                        <label id="mauticform_radiogrp_label_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_otro3" for="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_otro3" class="mauticform-radiogrp-label">
                            <input name="mauticform[cual_es_el_primer_sentimi]" class="mauticform-radiogrp-radio" id="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_otro3" type="radio" data-value="otro">
                            <div>
                                <input type="text">
                            </div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <span class="mauticform-errormsg" style="display: none;">This is required.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

La solución a esto es crear un pequeño script para activar el input de tipo texto, ya que entiendo que quieres que cuando no este marcado "Otro", este desahbilitado, asi que cuando se seleccione el 3er radio button, el script activara el input tipo texto.

Seria así (en JS vanilla):

```js
window.onload = function () {
        var radios = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('mauticform-radiogrp-radio'));
        var inputtexto = document.getElementById('inputexto');
        radios.forEach(radio => {
            radio.addEventListener('change', function () {
                if (radio.id === 'mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_otro3') {
                    inputtexto.disabled = false;
                }
                else {
                    inputtexto.disabled = true;
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

```html
<div class="cont_preguntas">
    <div id="mauticform_formulariolandingciudadcolorines_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi"
        data-validate="cual_es_el_primer_sentimi" data-validation-type="radiogrp"
        class="mauticform-row mauticform-radiogrp mauticform-field-4 mauticform-required">
        <label class="tex_pregunta" for="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Nostalgia1">¿Cuál es el
            primer sentimiento que te abraza?</label>
        <div class="mauticform-radiogrp-row">
        <div class="cont_radio">
                    Nostalgia
                </div>
            <label id="mauticform_radiogrp_label_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Nostalgia0"
                for="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Nostalgia0" class="mauticform-radiogrp-label">
                <input name="mauticform[cual_es_el_primer_sentimi]" class="mauticform-radiogrp-radio"
                    id="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Nostalgia0" type="radio" value="Nostalgia">
                
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="mauticform-radiogrp-row">
         <div class="cont_radio">
                    Alegría
                </div>
            <label id="mauticform_radiogrp_label_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Alegria1"
                for="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Alegria1" class="mauticform-radiogrp-label">
                <input name="mauticform[cual_es_el_primer_sentimi]" class="mauticform-radiogrp-radio"
                    id="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Alegria1" type="radio" value="Alegría">
               
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="mauticform-radiogrp-row">
        <div class="cont_radio">
                    Entusiasmo
                </div>
            <label id="mauticform_radiogrp_label_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Entusiasmo2"
                for="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Entusiasmo2" class="mauticform-radiogrp-label">
                <input name="mauticform[cual_es_el_primer_sentimi]" class="mauticform-radiogrp-radio"
                    id="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_Entusiasmo2" type="radio"
                    value="Entusiasmo">
                
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="mauticform-radiogrp-row">
        <div class="cont_radio">
                    Otro
                </div>
  
            <label id="mauticform_radiogrp_label_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_otro3"
                for="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_otro3" class="mauticform-radiogrp-label">
                <p>
                    <input name="mauticform[cual_es_el_primer_sentimi]" class="mauticform-radiogrp-radio"
                        id="mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_otro3" type="radio" data-value="otro">
                    <input type="text" id="inputexto" disabled>
                </p>
                

            </label>
        </div>
        <span class="mauticform-errormsg" style="display: none;">This is required.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

En caso de que quisieras que no se vea, donde pone la propiedad disabled puedes poner la propiedad hidden.

Si no entiendes cualquier cosa del código me consultas

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder a la pregunta, con tu explicación me quedo más que claro la duda
Solo tengo una pregunta ¿Cómo le puedo pasar el valor del input al radio? ¿Eso se puede? 
Lo que pasa es que con la base de datos toma lo valores del radio, pero cuando escoge la opción de texto ¿Cómo se puede enviar? ¿Solo le paso el parametro del nombre?

Comment: Si lo que deseas es poner el input del texto en el radio, deberas seleccionar el input del radio e igualar su valor al del input de tipo texto, en el caso anterior seria: radios[4].value=inputtexto.value , pero como dices puedes enviar el valor como parámetro desde el input de tipo texto, poniéndole el atributo name y el nombre con el que quieres pasarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracia por tu ayuda de nuevo.
Ya logré el envío a BD mediante radios[3].value=inputtexto.value ya me registra el valor que ingreso en el input, pero lo ingrese if (radio.id ... de Jquery, solamente que la primera vez me manda que el campo es requerido y cuando le doy de nuevo a enviar ya lo envía (tengo que darle dos veces a enviar) ¿donde podría colocar el código para solucionar que no detecta el input la primera vez?

Comment: ¿Donde le asignas el valor al radio?

Comment: Lo asigno en el if de esta forma

 if (radio.id === 'mauticform_radiogrp_radio_cual_es_el_primer_sentimi_otro3') {
                    inputtexto.disabled = false;
                   radios[3].value=inputtexto.value;
                }

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes conseguir con ayuda de css y javascript (jQuery en este caso):

```js
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(e) {
  if ($(this).val() == 3) {
    $('#op_3').removeClass('hidden');
  } else {
    $('#op_3').addClass('hidden');
  }
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenedor">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="opciones" value="1">
    Opcion 1
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="opciones" value="2">
    Opcion 2
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="opciones" value="3">
    Opcion 3
  </label>

  <input type="text" class="hidden" id="op_3">
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario, me ayudo bastante